# Windows 10 File Explorer replace desktop

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, desktop

This is a weird question but is it possible to replace the whole idea of the desktop and have File Explorer instead of the desktop, so when I open my PC it just has that instead of a desktop?

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qccft.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. It is from the Desktop where you manage your PC - functions that are not provided by Windows File Explorer.  The Windows Desktop is built right into Windows as a basic structure.

So *[is it possible to replace the whole idea of the desktop and have File Explorer instead of the desktop]*  No.

Comment: The Desktop *is* an **Explorer** window -- just with a specialized view -- borderless, transparent background, etc. Offhand, there are ways to modify an open window so that its only states are minimized and maximized or fullscreen (but can still be closed)-- might be close enough to what you want in a way that doesn't risk instability or a non-responsive system.